# Saving data from webservice calls to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, soap, spring-boot

My project is talking to a SOAP webservice and has a bunch of auto generated classes from a `wsdl` file.

When I make webservice calls I want to save the information from the response to a database but I want to write as little boilerplate code as possible and I don't want to have to duplicate all the attributes, getters and setters, from the webservice classes.

What I'd want to do is something like this (oversimplified):

```
WebserviceClass[] foo = WebserviceCall.getFoos();
for (WebserviceClass bar : foo){
    db.save(bar);
}
```

My project is in Spring Boot so I have been looking at Spring Data, Hibernate and such but all the solutions I find there require me to write a lot of my own classes and then instantiate from the Webservice classes (which calls for a lot of duplication of attributes, getters and setters).

Are there ways to build a schema from the autogenerated classes or the wsdl file? Can I write mappings without having to basically rewrite all the webservice classes?

This seems like it would be a solved problem but I haven't found a solution. Is there something I'm missing? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your generated classes and map them with JPA using @AttributeOverride.

```
@Entity(name="EVENT")
@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride( name="id", column=@Column(name="EVENT_ID",nullable=false)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="name", column=@Column(name="EVENT_NAME",nullable=false,length =50)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="date", column=@Column(name="EVENT_DATE_UTC", nullable=false)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="dateLocal", column=@Column(name="EVENT_DATE_LOCAL", nullable=false)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="state", column=@Column(name="STATE",nullable=false)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="operator", column=@Column(name="OPERATOR")),
    @AttributeOverride( name="deviceId", column=@Column(name="DEVICE_ID",nullable=false)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="deviceType", column=@Column(name="DEVICE_TYPE")),
    @AttributeOverride( name="deviceDescription", column=@Column(name="DEVICE_DESCRIPTION")),
    @AttributeOverride( name="description", column=@Column(name="EVENT_DESCRIPTION")),
    @AttributeOverride( name="priority", column=@Column(name="PRIORITY",nullable=false)),
    @AttributeOverride( name="attachment", column=@Column(name="ATTACHMENT")),
    @AttributeOverride( name="mimeType", column=@Column(name="MIME_TYPE")),
})
public class DbClass extends GeneratedClass {

    public DbClass(GeneratedClass generatedClass) {
        this.setName(generatedClass.getName());
        this.setDateLocal(generatedClass.getDateLocal());
        ...
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }
```

And then using a spring data repository over the DbClass:

```
springDataRepository.save(new DbClass(generatedClass));
```

It is not a very clean approach but it works.

Comment: I'm guessing its a typo that your class declaration says `DClass` but the constructor says `DbClass`?
   

But how does the `super(generatedClass);` constructor call work? My `GeneratedClass` has a `GeneratedClass()` constructor but I can not call  `super(generatedClass);` I get a "no suitable constructor found" error

Comment: It is true, you do not have that contructor. You can set all the attributes manually. I edited the answer.

Comment: So basically the `AttributeOverrides` annotation lists which attributes from the `GeneratedClass` to persist to the db and under which column name?

Comment: Exactly. And you can add more attributes llike the Id.